# Hide Campaign Start Date in Reports?

Tags: civicampaign

Does anyone know of a way to hide Campaign Start Dates from reports?

All I want to see is the campaign name in reports and dashboards.

Comment: Anyone have answer for this? If you're trying to import a report into Quickbooks and map the "Campaign" to "class", you can enter the date (exactly as formatted in report) in your Quickbooks class list. That being said, it's a workaround, and if someone has an answer that actually solves the problem, please post!